# How can i get part of the string from the array ? Index of?

Tags: java

Not sure how it's working in java.
In c# i used to use index of and substring.

```
private String[] ipaddresses = new String[]{
            "http://10.0.0.4:8098/?cmd=nothing",
            "http://10.0.0.3:8098/?cmd=nothing"};
    private String iptouse = "";
```

I want to assign to iptouse the first index of the array ipaddresses but only part of the index:

```
iptouse = "http://10.0.0.4:8098/?cmd=" + "start";
```

It's only example what i want is to extract from the sting in index 0 only this part: http://10.0.0.4:8098/?cmd=

Answer (score 1):

You can process it with [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) class or with Apache Commons [StringUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) (they have a handful of cool methods for text parsing).
However, the propper way would be to use Java [URI class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URI.html).

There you have a very handy methods for extracting the host and the query part etc. To understand it better read about the structure of URI [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme)

In your case it would be something like:

```
URI u = new URI("http://10.0.0.4:8098/?cmd=nothing");
String upToQuery = u.getScheme()+u.getAuthority()+u.getPath();
```

Answer (score 0):

It's the same in Java use substring() and indexOf:

```
String iptouse = ipaddresses[0].substring(0,ipaddresses[0].indexOf('=')+1)+"start";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
String symbol="=";
String iptouse =ipaddresses[0].split(symbol)[0]+symbol+"start";
```

Or

```
replaceFirst("nothing", "start");
```